# When did “word” become a synonym of “promise” for the first time?

Tags: meaning, word-usage, etymology, synonyms, history

We know that the word *word* can sometimes be a synonym for *promise*, as in:

1. You have my word.

to mean:

2. You have my promise.

And I haven’t seen any other sentence structures that *word* is used to mean promise in them.

My question: When did *word* become a synonym for *promise* for the first time?

Comment: MODERATOR NOTE: Use comments only to ask for more information about the question or to suggest improvements to the question. Answers in comments will be removed.

Comment: Maybe a follow-up question: what's older, "word" in the sense of "promise" or "word" in the sense of "atom of a sentence"?

Comment: There's a metaphor of transfer involved -- it's not just the word _word_. There are constructions like _I give you my word; You have my word_ where something is pledged and owed. But _word_ is just short for whatever words are exchanged (and their form, which must be correct or it doesn't count). As for when that happened, I leave it to the answers.

Comment: It's right to note that the phrase is an idiom.

Answer (score 10):

From the online resource, *[Middle English Compendium](https://quod.lib.umich.edu/m/middle-english-dictionary/dictionary/MED53418/track?counter=1&search_id=38707154)*

> 4. ***word***
>    (a) A command, an edict, a royal decree, etc.; an expressed request, (someone’s) bidding; hunt. & hawk. a call or command to a hound or falcon; wordes of livere, ?instructions, directions; ?an authorized order; **(b)** an assurance, a guarantee; (someone’s) pledge, **promise, word of honor;** a statement of intent; also, an oath; holden (kepen) ~; (c) a prophecy, prediction; (d) a boast; blustering; also, a threat; gret (heigh, proud) wordes; (e) a word or series of words used in ritual, prayer, incantation; also, a prayer, an incantation.

Quotation

> - Ðet wæs first seo kyning Wulfere þe þet feostnode **first mid his worde** & siððon mid his fingre ge wrat on Cristes mel.
>   Source:[Peterborough Chronicle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterborough_Chronicle), a1121

A very rough translation

- …confirmed first by his word and later with his fingers written on the crucifix

GEdgar's answer which cites an earlier instance dates from 1008. I found, what appears a trustworthy translation, in a series of papers dedicated to Alfred the Great entitled [*Alfred the Wise*](https://books.google.it/books?id=t4i_yF6Daw8C&pg=PA219&lpg=PA219&dq=%22Gif%20ge%20nylla%C3%B0%20healdan%20eower%20word%20and%20eower%20wedd%22,&source=bl&ots=oN4-aZbuEN&sig=ACfU3U2U7OmsRaXnhDSumeO4XMPmObVDUw&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQwfHKrumBAxU-QvEDHUXMBCUQ6AF6BAgIEAM#v=onepage&q&f=false)  printed in 1997

> The similarly confirmative, alliterating word-pair *word and wedd* occurs twice in the laws: King Æthelred’s code of 1008 [V Atr.5],
> *goðence word & wedd þe he God betœhte* ‘let (every monk) consider the word and pledge that he gave to God’, and similarly King Æthelred’s Laws issued at King’s Enham [VI Atr. 3a], both [Wulfstanian](https://www.oxfordreference.com/display/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803125127553?p=emailAoKK4kT3jC1oY&d=/10.1093/oi/authority.20110803125127553). It occurs in a homily not now attributed to Wulfstan: *and gif ge nyllað healdan **eower word and eower wedd**, ge þonne beoð adilegode of ealra lifigendra bocum* ‘and if you will not keep **your word and your pledge**, then you will be blotted out from the books of all the living’. It occurs once in the Anglo-Saxon Chronicle, in the annal for 1014, versions C, D, and E: *& man þa fulne freondscipe gefœstnode **mid worde & mid wedde** on œgþre healfe* ‘And then a complete compact of friendship was confirmed **with word and with pledge** on either side’[…]

Answer (score 8):

> When did “word” become a synonym of “promise” for the first time?

This a question for historical linguistics, and such questions are usually unanswerable because the ideas of a language might actually predate a language itself and languages themselves don't, strictly speaking, have beginnings and ends. If Modern English has the expression, "to give one's word", then it seems Middle and Old English do too, which then begs the question is it proto-Germanic? For instance, if a speaker of the Bokmål, uses the same construction to communicate the same meaning, then likely there has never been English where 'to give a word' was never used, and that's because there is not strict dividing line between proto-Germanic, Frisian, Old English, Middle English, etc. In fact, dialects of languages are difficult to define as dialects in opposition to distinct languages, a fact that Scots and Veneto speakers might realize given their often contested statuses as distinct languages. The fact that OED has examples going back to old English doesn't necessarily mean that the idiom began there. It may very well go back to the Romans, in which case on Latin Stack Exchange, you might be able to ask the same question and date the idiom back to the beginning of Latin. And even then, who is to say that it wasn't used well before its first known archaeological appearance? The idiom may have been used by the putative speakers of [PIE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-European_language).

Comment: The implication in these questions is usually the first attestation in written English language as we are on EL&U and we can often answer that. The OP could have asked more explicitly and there is the etymology tag. Some words/phrases go as far back to Old English and in some cases, borrowed from Latin, Greek, Germanic etc., and _OED_ often mentions them. Etymonline usually gives the PIE origins/roots as well. Some words are traced back to the oldest languages in the world, like _water_. Nice explanation about historical linguistics though.

Comment: As a note, this construction of "to give one's word" also exists in both Slavic languages I speak - Russian and Serbian - so there's a decent chance it's not even a Germanic construct. Maybe it goes all the way back to PIE, who knows?

Comment: @Mash and in Czech as well, so it's all three Slavic language families :-)

Comment: To your point, consider the Jewish tradition of covenants. Numbers 30:2: "When a man voweth a vow unto the Lord, or sweareth an oath to bind his soul with a bond, he shall not break his word; he shall do according to all that proceedeth out of his mouth."

Comment: Are you sure that's not just a product of the translation? @Blackhawk

Comment: @Mash I don't know Hebrew, but as far as I can tell, the word here ( דְּבָר֑וֹ - da-ba-row) has the root דָבָר (dabar) which is always translated in the Bible as "words" or "speech".  So it seems very likely that not only is that the correct literal meaning for the verse from ancient Hebrew, but also it is very likely that the equivalence of "Your Word" = "Your Promise" is biblical and that's how it spread to to all of medieval Europe.

Comment: @Mash As one who understands Hebrew,  in this case, "word/speech" is a direct translation from the Hebrew.

Comment: @Mash I definitely considered that "break his word" was probably idiomatic to the translator, but the second part "do according to all that proceedeth out of his mouth" seemed more likely to be a transliteration and still relevant in this case.

Answer (score 5):

"To keep one's word" ...
For this sense, [Oxford English Dictionary](https://www.oed.com/dictionary/word_n?tab=meaning_and_use#126609407) (subscription required) has examples back to Old English

> Gif ge nyllað healdan eower word and eower wedd, ge þonne beoð adilegode of ealra lifigendra bocum.

tchrist points out this definition... "A promise, a pledge, an undertaking; a guarantee. Almost always with possessive."  This also has quotations back to Old English.  Here is a more recent one from 1393:

> It sit wel every wiht To kepe his word in trowthe upryht.

Comment: Can you give a year?

Comment: No, you need sense 1.7.a. “A promise, a pledge, an undertaking; a guarantee. Almost always with possessive.” The first citation is Se cyning [*sc.* Herod]..nolde þeah for his aðe ne for þam gebeorum his word awægen.
*Catholic Homilies: 1st Series* (Royal MS.) (1997) xxxii. 451 Ælfric of Eynsham (c950–c1010), Benedictine abbot of Eynsham and scholar.

Comment: @SnackExchange This is a use from time immemorial, since before you would recognize English as English, and from before that even further. The first documented use in English was during the first millennium, back when we numbered years in fewer digits than we use today. This is hardly limited to English. You can find this in other modern languages as well, such as French *parole* and Spanish *palabra*, whose etymon is Ancient Greek *παραβολή* and which was used in the Koine in the New Testament. It would little surprise me to find it in Gilgamesh.

Comment: And can you please add a translation of the quoted text as well?

Comment: παραβολή seems to be the origin of *parabola* as well.

Comment: @tchrist And those are just comments? Sounds like an answer to me.

Comment: But there's a strange thing regarded to *παραβολή*. The third letter is /r/, the fifth letter is /b/, and the seventh letter is /l/ (Parabola). How is this the etymon for Spanish *palabra* which has a different order of those letters?

Comment: @SnackExchange From *παραβολή* Old Spanish once had *parabla* where Modern Spanish now has *palabra* and Modern Portuguese now has *palavra*; see also English *palaver*. Long-distance reciprocal metathesis of /r/ and /l/ like this has often occurred historically in many languages, including in Western Romance such as Spanish, Portuguese, Galician, Asturian, Gascon, French, and some Italian. Other examples include L. *miraculum* > ES *milagro*, Gal/PT *milagre*; L. *periculum* > ES *peligro*, Ast *peligru*. See [this related question](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/34865).

Comment: @Lambie Because I have what some would view as a conflict of interest here, I would prefer to recommend possible improvements to this answer instead.

Comment: Then just [edit] them in. You don't need a license.

Comment: @SnackExchange the point is that using a word meaning _word_ or _speech_ to mean a promise is a ubiquitous feature, found in many modern and ancient languages. Modern Greek, for example, has giving one's _λόγος_ (logos, speech, spoken word) to mean _promise_ and this is basically the same use as giving one's word, or parole, or palabra.

Comment: @tchrist Matthew 5:37 in Westcott-Hort’s text begins εστω δε ο λογος υμων. KJV renders it as “But let your communication be …” rather than “let your word be,” which I incorrectly remembered as a succinct supporting example for your point and which is how some more recent translations *do* render it. (Yes, I realize λογος has a broad range of meaning.)

Comment: @tchrist I'd have to check to see if it's used that way in Gilgamesh, but AFAIK the Akkadian word for "word" ([_awātum_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aw%C4%81tum)) could indeed be used in the sense of "promise" (in addition to many other meanings). I suspect the same is true for the Sumerian _inim_.

Comment: @SnackExchange you're talking about a language that calls the country to its southeast on the other side of the Mediterranean [Argelia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argelia).

Comment: @terdon in biblical Hebrew one can certainly use "word" metaphorically to mean "promise." Now I'm going to see if it's ever used that way literally

Comment: @phoog - Don't forget murciélago, which "should" be murciégalo ("blind mouse"). Or brid and hros (bird and horse).